# Why can't the pH of a solution of a weak acid be calculated without the dissociation constant?

Tags: acid-base

Why can't the pH of a solution of a  weak acid be calculated without the dissociation constant? How can pH of weak base be determined?

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know the dissociation constant decides the degree of dissociation at that temperature and hence if you don't know how much the compound dissociates then how can you determine the concentration of it's component(which here is an acid having hydrogen atom as its component).